# Relay with mutation for a React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-java

I keep on facing the same error :

Uncaught Error: Relay transform error. Your schema defines a mutation field `addItem` that takes 7 arguments, but mutation fields must have exactly one argument named `input`.`` in file `../AddItemMutation.js`. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added.

Where should I declare the input argument in my implementation?
I have a SimpleForm component which gets the input data and it should use Relay to send GraphQL queries.

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class AddItemMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {addItem}`;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
     newName: this.props.name
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on Item
      {
        id,
        name,
        owner{
           name
        },
        authorizedBy,
        authorizedOn,
        dateFrom,
        dateTo
    }`;
  }

  getConfigs() {
   return [{
    type: 'REQUIRED_CHILDREN',
    children: [Relay.QL`
      fragment on Item
      {
       id,
       name,
       owner{
         name
       },
       authorizedBy,
       authorizedOn,
       dateFrom,
       dateTo
     }`]
   }];
 }
}
```

The schema is generated with graphql-java library and the field of mutation addItem of type Item takes : newName, newId, newDateFrom, newDateTo, newAuthorizedBy, newAuthorizedOn, newOwner;

Comment: Your GraphQL Schema is not compatible with Relay, as Relay needs all input arguments for mutations to be wrapped in an input object called `input`.